# How can I move/copy span value and put it to another div using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I move/copy the price and put it inside the `<div class="info">` using jQuery?

I'm using this code but it gives me an answer of "102030".

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".items .price").appendTo(".info");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">10</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">20</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">30</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Which price? You currently have 3 spans with a price class. Which value are you trying to move into the info div? Are you trying to get a sum maybe?

Comment: No sir, i just want to move/copy the price inside the <div class="info">

Comment: Just for reference, your existing code appends all `.price` elements to every `.info` element. See [appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your `items` div and use `.find('.price').text()` to get value of price and add that value inside `info` div using `.text()`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".items").each(function() {
//find price value and assign it to info div
  $(this).find(".info").text($(this).find(".price").text())
  //$(this).find(".price").remove() //if want to remove price div
})
```

```css
.info {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">10</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">20</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">30</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Every element's price and `.append()` it into `.info` by using `.each()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".items").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".info").append($(this).find(".price"))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">10</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">20</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="price">30</span>
    <img src="/url" alt="" />
    <div class="info">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move/copy price to another div or tag using javacript/jquery using below example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".items").each(function(){
   var price = $(this).find('.price').text();
   $(this).find('.info').text(price);
  });
```

use this I hope it will work